# nginx - block/allow by domain name (rather than ip)?

Tags: nginx, configuration, apache2

In Apache you can allow/deny access by domain name as well as by ip address.

In Nginx I know how to allow/deny by ip address but how do I do that by domain name ?

(Secondary concern doesn't it produce horrible performance problems as you take incoming ip address and do a reverse DNS on it ?).

Comment: https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/modules/rdns/

Comment: @HBruijn:  That's great, thanks. If you want to make it into an answer I could mark it as correct.